# Video does not play through even if enough content has been appended

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, buffer, media-source

I have a setup where I send a 10min long video (Elephants Dream) using the websockets protocol chunked in short segments of 4s each.
I use the browser as client, with the [Websocket API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-websockets-20110419/) to receive the content and the HTML5 Video Tag as player, to which I append the chunks as they come to the video using [Media Source Extensions](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/).

The thing is that there seems to be a limit somewhere (max receive buffer size, max mediasource sourcebuffer buffer size, max buffered content on video element, etc) so that the video does not play correctly to the end but stops earlier even if there is enough data.

All of the segments are arriving correctly and get appended in time. At the same time, the video starts playing back from the beginning. 
You can see the grey line on the player showing buffered video grow until at some point in time where it stops growing and the video stops playing when getting to this position. 
However, the full video has been appended to the mediasource element, regarding to the output messages, and which can also be tested by manually jumping to another position in future or past. It looks like there is always just a fraction of the content "loaded".

Since I'm testing it on localhost the throughput is very high so I tried lowering this to more common values (still good over video bitrate) to see if I'm overloading the client but this did not change anything.

Also tried different segment sizes, with exact same results, except for that the time in point where it stops is a different one.

[image: Video player stopping]

[image: Console output at that moment]

Any idea on where this limitation can be or what may be happening?

Comment: Is there any message on the browser console when the video stops playback? Also, it would help if you can share your code as it may be something else that is happening each time you append a chunk that is actually causing the problem. It would be worth checking on different browsers also as MSE is relatively new and there will be subtle differences in the differs browsers implementations.

Comment: @Mick no, there is no error message, everything looks normal, just the video playback stops. 
I have found out that the problem occurs only when the segment to play is of a different representation (MPEG-DASH representation). May the problem be that this has different width and height or different bandwidth? The framerate is the same for all representations.

I find it very strange that if you manually jump in time the content really is playable but does not reproduce automatically as it does when the next segment has the same quality level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a gap in the buffered data. Browsers have a limited buffer size to which you can append. When that limit is reached, if you append additional data, the browser will silently free some space by discarding some frames it does not need from the buffer. In my experience, if you happen too fast, you may end up with gaps in your buffer. You should monitor the status of the `buffered` attribute when appending to see if there is any gap.

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing representations right before it stops? When you change representations, you need to append the init segment for the new representation before you append the next segment of the new representation.